# How to return only two value in a loop

Tags: laravel

The app is all about scoring video uploaded online, with adjudicators of different category.

I have in my controller

```
$watched = Upload::with('scoresheet')->get();
```

There is a reletionship between upload and scoresheet.
In my controller, I am using "with" to grab the relationship eagerly, so that I can get who scored a video.

Now I am trying to loop through and displaying scored or unscored with the `ifesle` statement if they satisfy this condition

```
@foreach($watched as $scoredvideo)
    @foreach($scoredvideo->scoresheet as $seen)
        @if($seen->user_id == Auth::user()->id && $seen->upload_id == $video->id)
            Scored
        @else
            Not Scored
        @endif
    @endforeach 
@endforeach
```

but, it kept on returning the message of the numbers of video that have been scored.

See below
[image]

Here, three videos have been scored.

I tried using break, it only display the true value which is 'scored' and terminate the loop.

How can I solve this this?

Comment: how to get $ video-> id?

Comment: can you display the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but if I understand it correctly you are trying to know whether a logged in user has scored the video or not. I would do it something like this.

```
@foreach($videos as $video)

    //render the video object however you want in your view

    //and use this if to know if the logged in user has already scored the video
    @if($video->Scoresheet()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->exists())
        scored
    @else
        Not Scored

@endforeach
```